# If `self` is always the implied receiver in Ruby, why doesn't `self.puts` work?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, my understanding is that `self` is the implied receiver for any bare method call. However:

```
~: irb
>> puts "foo"
foo
=> nil
>> self.puts "foo"
NoMethodError: private method `puts' called for main:Object
```

What explains this?

In case it's any help:

```
>> method(:puts).owner
=> Kernel
```

Comment: try `self.send :puts, "foo"`. You can get around private methods with send.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Private methods can't have a receiver

I think the answer is this: Ruby's way of enforcing method privacy is that it doesn't allow calling private methods with an explicit receiver.

An example:

```
class Baker
  def bake_cake
    make_batter
    self.use_oven # will explode: called with explicit receiver 'self'
  end

  private
  def make_batter
    puts "making batter!"
  end

  def use_oven
    puts "using oven!"
  end

end

b = Baker.new
b.bake_cake
```

Since there can be no explicit receiver, you certainly can't do `b.use_oven`. And that is how method privacy is enforced.

Comment: but puts is a public method , method(:puts).owner.public_methods.grep /puts/ returns [:puts] . MRI ruby 1.93p194

Comment: sorry ， i forgot the method lookup .  self.class.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Comment: @dfang - maybe it's re-classified as private by a child class?

Answer (score 4):

Because that's the definition of privacy in Ruby: private methods can only be called with an implicit receiver.

Actually, there's an exception to this rule: because `foo = bar` *always* creates a local variable, you are allowed to call private setters like `self.foo = bar`, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to call them *at all* (without using reflection).

Comment: As well as using reflection, you can do `foo=(bar)` without using `self`.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Doesn't work, I just tried it. It also makes sense that is doesn't work, because parentheses can be used for expression grouping, so that's a perfectly valid local variable assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that `self` is the implied receiver when you don't specify one explicitly. The reason that you're not allowed to do `self.puts` is that you may not call private methods with an explicit receiver (even if that receiver is `self`) and as the error message says, `puts` is a private method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access private methods in ruby using the `self.` syntax, or generally speaking using any receiver (something in front of the `.`). That is only possible for protected methods.